# the number of users online and number of active session

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, session, iis-7

My environment is ASP.Net + IIS 7.0 + Windows Server 2008 + .Net 3.5. I am wondering whether the number of users online and number of active session are the same thing? The other question is, no matter whether they are the same, how to calculate them (i.e. for a given time, what is the number of users online, and related active number of sessions)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To you first question, sessions and users are not the same. Each user has a session, but some sessions are not active and do not have users any more. Such sessions are ended automatically by the asp.net engine after a timeout period. i.e. since http is a disconnected protocol, the web server has no way of knowing if the user is between requests or has just abandoned the session.

If you want to track the number of active session, you can use the session_start and session_end methods of the globals.asax file.
You can have a simple counter that increments on start and decrements on end.

Comment: Thanks Elad! Do you mean session is only becoming not active when timeout? (i.e. before timeout, sessions are all treated as active)? If timeout is not the only case which will make session inactive, any other cases?

Comment: Note, session_end will only be called if using in memory session state. Using out of process state (state service) or database and it will not be called.

Comment: If I use memory based session state, I am wondering whether session is only becoming not active when timeout? (i.e. before timeout, sessions are all treated as active)? If timeout is not the only case which will make session inactive, any other cases?

Comment: The session is removed from memory in one of two ways, either a timeout or you end it through code (On some user event like logout, etc.). As I said, IIS and ASP.NET have no way of knowing if the session is between requests or dead aside from a long time without a request from that sessio.

Comment: Thanks Elad, question answered.